# Is there any way to compare two faces using emguCV in C#?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, face-recognition

I need to compare just two faces if it is for the same person or not ... 
I convert this project [Face detection and recognition in runtime](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239849/Multiple-face-detection-and-recognition-in-real) to compare two faces but the method always return true .

```
        int ImagesCount = 0;
        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
        List<Mat> TrainedFaces = new List<Mat>();
        List<int> PersonsLabes = new List<int>();
        Mat image1 = img1.ToImage<Gray, byte>().Mat;
        Mat image1Temp = img1.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Mat;

        foreach (Rectangle face in faceDetector.DetectMultiScale(image1, 1.2, 10, new Size(50, 50), Size.Empty))
        {
            Image<Gray, byte> trainedImage = ImageClass.CropImage(image1.ToBitmap(), face).ToImage<Gray, byte>().Resize(200, 200, Inter.Cubic);
            CvInvoke.EqualizeHist(trainedImage, trainedImage);
            TrainedFaces.Add(trainedImage.Mat);
            PersonsLabes.Add(ImagesCount);
            ImagesCount++;
        }

        EigenFaceRecognizer recognizer = new EigenFaceRecognizer(ImagesCount, 2000);
        recognizer.Train(TrainedFaces.ToArray(), PersonsLabes.ToArray());

        Mat image2 = img2.ToImage<Gray, byte>().Mat;
        Rectangle[] rect = faceDetector.DetectMultiScale(image2, 1.2, 10, new Size(50, 50), Size.Empty);
        if (rect.Length == 1)
        {
            Image<Gray, Byte> grayFaceResult = ImageClass.CropImage(image2.ToBitmap(), rect[0]).ToImage<Gray, byte>().Resize(200, 200, Inter.Cubic);
            CvInvoke.EqualizeHist(grayFaceResult, grayFaceResult);
            var result = recognizer.Predict(grayFaceResult);
            if (result.Label != -1 && result.Distance < 2000)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
```

Note: The first image may contain more than one picture of the same person and the second image should always contain one picture of the another or same person but always give me 0 ( Always return true Although I tried two pictures of two different people ) and I used emguCv 4.3

I searched a lot but I didn't found any thing can resolve me problem
Is there anyone who can know my mistake in this code or can give me a link for another solution for compare two faces ?
(Note: I am new to this field)

Answer (score 0):

If you can deploy a python application on your server, you might adopt [deepface](https://github.com/serengil/deepface). It has a verify function and you should send the base64 encoded images as inputs to those functions.

Endpoint: http://127.0.0.1:5000/verify

Body:

```
  {
    "model_name": "VGG-Face",
    "img": [
        {
                "img1": "data:image/jpeg;base64,..."
                , "img2": "data:image/jpeg;base64,..."  
        }
    ]
  }
```